# .htaccess issue with modernizr (Unexpected token <)

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, modernizr

I'm having issues with Modernizr throwing an 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <'

When I click the error in Chrome dev tools it reports the error as being on the first line at .

After some debugging I think I've narrowed the issue down weirdly to htaccess rewrites I have going on.

Here's what I have in my htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^faqs/ ./faqs.php
```

If I visit /faqs/I get the error. If I visit just /faqs.php there is no error. That's how I'm coming to the conclusion that the issue lies in this rewrite.

Has anyone seen anything like this before? Any ideas on a fix?

Cheers

Comment: Try making first line to `Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews`

Comment: I managed to solve it! I was calling Modenizr in the file with <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script> I needed to call it with <script src="/js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script> instead. That's seemed to of worked!

Comment: I would assume you would have had a client-side error (in the console) that it couldn't find the file?

Comment: Yeah I would have as well but nothing. Maybe it was finding the file but then some reason it needed to know it's absolute position? It's a bit of a mystery.